# Unable to store contract on Archway Constantine testnet

Tags: archway-network, cosmwasm

I am facing an issue when trying to store a contract on the Archway constantine testnet. The log shows:

`"raw_log":"tx fee 1538583aconst is less than min fee: 5538898800000000000aconst: insufficient fee"`

The following command was used:

```
RES=$(archwayd tx wasm store artifacts/cw_nameservice.wasm --from mywallet --node https://rpc.constantine.archway.tech:443 --chain-id constantine-3 --gas-prices 0.25aconst --gas auto --gas-adjustment 1.3 -y --output json -b block)
```

What could be the possible issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the introduction of the **Minimum Price of Gas** (https://github.com/archway-network/archway/blob/main/docs/adr/ADR-005-minimum-price-of-gas.md) and the increase in the network's native token's decimal precision from 10^6 to 10^18, it is not recommended to set arbitrary values for the price of gas.

To get the minimum price of gas you can use the following command:

```
RES=$(archwayd q rewards estimate-fees 1 --node 'https://rpc.constantine.archway.tech:443' --output json | jq -r '.gas_unit_price | (.amount + .denom)')
```

The above command would replace the **0.25aconst** value in your original command. The complete command would be:

```
RES=$(archwayd tx wasm store artifacts/cw_nameservice.wasm --from mywallet --node https://rpc.constantine.archway.tech:443 --chain-id constantine-3 --gas-prices $(archwayd q rewards estimate-fees 1 --node 'https://rpc.constantine.archway.tech:443' --output json | jq -r '.gas_unit_price | (.amount + .denom)') --gas auto --gas-adjustment 1.3 -y --output json -b block)
```

Comment: As a note, this answer relies on the JQ package. It can be installed in Linux via apt-get, yum, dnf, etc. With `sudo apt-get install jq`, `sudo dnf install jq`, `sudo yum install jq` etc. It can be installed on MacOS using Homebrew: `brew install jq`.